# Generate CDF plot with markers

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Seems like a trivial ask but I can't figure out how to plot my raw CDF data and place markers. Here's what data looks like:

```
10.45 925.0
20.56 928.0
30.63 948.0
50.10 955.0
80.62 961.0
90.00 978.0
98.89 1026.0
```

col 1 is % and col 2 is value. So, for example, 10.45% users store 925 MB or less. I want to:

1. Draw a png chart of CDF
2. Have markers on this chart for 10%, 50%, 90%, 99%.
   How can I achieve this in python? I have basically no plotting experience.

Answer (score 1):

The raw CDF can be plotted using [`step`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.step.html). You can choose how to draw the steps: `pre` means line for `y[i]` drawn from `x[i-1]` to `x[i]` (default) or `post` from `x[i]` to `x[i+1]`.

(I assume you mean ticks and maybe grid lines on the y axis when you speak of markers, otherwise it would be unclear where to put the marker if your data contain an entry for the exact marker value, e.g. for 90 %).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([[  10.45,  925.  ],
       [  20.56,  928.  ],
       [  30.63,  948.  ],
       [  50.1 ,  955.  ],
       [  80.62,  961.  ],
       [  90.  ,  978.  ],
       [  98.89, 1026.  ]])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ticks = [10, 50, 90, 99]
ticklabels = [f'{t} %' for t in ticks]

ax1.step(a[:,1], a[:,0], where='pre')  # default
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks(ticks)
ax1.yaxis.set_ticklabels(ticklabels)
ax1.yaxis.grid(True)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 100)
ax1.set_title('pre')

ax2.step(a[:,1], a[:,0], where='post')
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks(ticks)
ax2.yaxis.set_ticklabels(ticklabels)
ax2.yaxis.grid(True)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 100)
ax2.set_title('post')
```

[image]